# Alternate between show_sql = false and show_sql = true during debugging session

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I was wondering if is there any alternative to alternate between `spring.jpa.show_sql=false` and `spring.jpa.show_sql=true` during a debugging session. I mean: without restarting the application.